# How to perform file / directory manipulation with user privileges in mind?

Tags: unix, privileges, file-manipulation

I have a server application that will be running under a system account because at any given time, it will be processing requests on behalf of any user on the system. These requests consist of instructions for manipulating the filesystem.

Here's the catch: the program needs to keep that particular user's privileges in mind when performing the actions. For example, `joe` should not be able to modify `/home/larry` if its permissions are `755`.

Currently my strategy is this

- Get the owner / group of the file
- Compare it to the user ID / group ID of the user trying to perform the action
- If either match (or if none match), use the appropriate part of the permission field in the file to either allow or deny the action

Is this wise? Is there an easier way to do this?

At first, I was thinking of having multiple instances of the app running under the user's accounts - but this is not an option because then only one of the instances can listen on a given TCP port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [samba](http://www.samba.org) for an example of this can be done. The samba daemon runs as root but forks and assumes the credentials of a normal user as soon as possible.

Unix systems have two separate sets of credentials: the real user/group ids and the effective user/group ids. The real set identifies who you actually are, and the effective set defines what you can access. You can change the effective uid/gid as you please if you are root—including to an ordinary user and back again—as your real user/group ids remain root during the transition. So an alternative way to do this in a single process is to use `seteuid/gid` to apply the permissions of different users back and forth as needed. If your server daemon runs as root or has `CAP_SETUID` then this will be permitted.

However, notice that if you have the ability to switch the effective uid/gid at whim and your application is subverted, then that subversion could for example switch the effective uid/gid back to 0 and you could have a serious security vulnerability. This is why it is prudent to drop all privileges permanently as soon as possible, including your real user uid/gid.

For this reason it is normal and safer to have a single listening socket running as root, then fork off and change both the real and effective user ids by calling `setuid`. Then it cannot change back. Your forked process would have the socket that was `accept()`ed as it is a fork. Each process just closes the file descriptors they don't need; the sockets stay alive as they are referenced by the file descriptors in the opposite processes.

You could also try and enforce the permissions by examining them individually yourself, but I hope it is obvious that this is potentially error-prone, has lots of edge cases and more likely to go wrong (eg. it won't work with POSIX ACLs unless you specifically implement that too).

So, you have three options:

1. Fork and `setgid()`/`setuid()` to the user you want. If communication is required, use `pipe(2)` or `socketpair(2)` before you fork.
2. Don't fork and `seteuid()`/`setegid()` around as needed (less secure: more likely to compromise your server by accident).
3. Don't mess with system credentials; do permission enforcement manually (less secure: more likely to get authorisation wrong).

If you need to communicate with the daemon, then although it might be harder to do it down a socket or a pipe, the first option really is the proper secure way to go about it. See [how ssh does privilege separation](http://www.citi.umich.edu/u/provos/ssh/privsep.html), for example. You might also consider if can change your architecture so instead of any communication the process can just share some memory or disk space instead.

You mention that you considered having a separate process run for each user, but need a single listening TCP port. You can still do this. Just have a master daemon listen on the TCP port and dispatch requests to each user daemon and communicate as required (eg. via Unix domain sockets). This would actually be almost the same as having a forking master daemon; I think the latter would turn out to be easier to implement.

Further reading: the `credentials(7)` manpage. Also note that Linux has file system uid/gids; this is almost the same as effective uid/gids except for other stuff like sending signals. If your users don't have shell access and cannot run arbitrary code then you don't need to worry about the difference.

Comment: Thank you for a very well-written answer! Would it be possible to create a master process that listens on a port and then forwards the data to another process over another socket connection? Is that what you're saying in your second-to-last paragraph?

Comment: Yes, that's right, and you could do that. However, based on everything you said I'm pretty sure that it'd be easier and simpler for you to implement a forking master listening daemon and have the child drop privileges. The forked process will automatically have access to the request socket just as the master daemon does; no need to communicate that part.

Comment: Okay. I'm looking for a solution that will work well with Qt as well, although it's not a requirement. So I take that into consideration when deciding the right approach.

Comment: As far as I know doing this with `fork()` will work just fine with Qt, but of course then it will no longer be cross-platform since Windows has no such concept.

Comment: Thank you! I accepted your answer and awarded the bounty - your answer was extremely helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I would have my server fork() and immediately `setuid(uid)` to give up root privileges.   Then any file manipulation would be on behalf of the user you've become.   Since you're a child of the server you'd still hold the accept()ed child socket that the request (and I assume response) would go on.   This (obviously) requires root privilege on the daemon.

Passing file descriptors between processes seems unnecessarily complicated in this case, as the child already has the "request" descriptor.

Comment: Hmmm... that's certainly a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Let one server run on the previlegued server port, and spawn child processes for users that log into the system. The child processes should drop privilegues and inpersonate the user that logged in. Now the childs cannot do harm anymore.

Comment: Yes, but how are the connections transferred from the server to the child processes?

Comment: I believe this works by letting the root process set up the socket, and then just pass the file descriptor to the child. I don't know how this is done exactly, but at least PostgreSQL works in a similar manner, where for each connection, a child process is spawned to handle it. And I cannot believe all the traffic has to be routed through the main process, so it will be some fd passing there.

Comment: Well... I'll look into it. This does make things more complicated, though because then the child processes have to communicate with the parent.